# count number of unique integers from multiple ranges to calculate horizontal coverage of blast result

Tags: language-agnostic

When I tried to map/align DNA sequence reads to protein database, I could not find many mapping tools which provide horizontal reference/subject sequence coverage, however blastx/diamond does aligned Start and End location on reference genes per query reads. Thus I needed to calculate the number of unique integers from multiple ranges [subjectStart..subjectEnd] per reference genes to get the length of aligned sequences.

blastx/diamond output were trimmed to 3 columns for ref gene ID, Start and End using `awk -F"\t" '{if ($2 <= $3) {print $0} else {print $1"\t"$3"\t"$2}}'` to fix reverse sequences. Each Row ID may or may not have ranges overlapped or duplicated each other, and those duplicated numbers need to be counted only once.

input

```
ID  Start   End
A   1   50
A   2   45
A   25  150
A   50  150
A   155 200
A   205 300
B   5   50
B   61  70
B   81  100
C   1   500`
```

Desired output.

```
ID  count
A   292
B   76
C   500
```

I requested the help to get the desired output in the first edition of this Ask, and I could get the perfect solutions promptly from many experts!!!
Followings work perfect for me and I learned a lot. I sincerely appreciate you all!!!

## Ruby by @dawg

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new() }}
    h[$F[0]].merge(($F[1].to_i..$F[2].to_i)) if $.>1
END{
    puts "ID\tCount"
    h.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}\t#{v.length}"}
}
' Input.file > Output.file
```

## Perl by @zdim

```
 perl -MData::Dumper -MList::Util=uniq -wnE'
    ($id, $beg, $end) = split; 
    next if not $beg or $beg =~ /[^0-9]/ or not $end or $end =~ /[^0-9]/;
    push @{$res{$id}}, $beg..$end; 
    }{ 
    for (keys %res) { $res{$_} = uniq sort { $a <=> $b } @{$res{$_}} };
    say Dumper \%res
' Input.file > Output.file
```

## Awk by @pmf

```
 awk 'NR>1 {s[$1] += $3 - ($2 <= b[$1] ? ($3 <= b[$1] ? $3 : b[$1]) + 1 : $2) + 1; b[$1] = b[$1] <= $3 ? $3 : b[$1]} END {OFS="\t"; print "ID", "count"; for (i in s) {print i, s[i]}}' Input.file > Output.file
```

## Awk by @dawg

```
 awk '
FNR>1{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) ss[$1 "|" i]}
END{
    print "ID", "Count"
    for (e in ss) {
        split(e,idx,"\|")
        cnt[idx[1]]++
    }
    for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]
}
' OFS="\t" Input.file > Output.file
```

Comment: Is the input sorted (as in your sample)?

Comment: It is sorted by ID but can be sorted by any variables. Thanks!!!

Comment: Where's some code that you tried?  Please show us what you have done about it yourself?

Comment: With `awk` you can operate linewise without loading the whole file into memory, only storing the current boundary and the actual sum for each group. Use with a fully sorted input: `awk 'NR>1 {s[$1] += $3 - ($2 <= b[$1] ? ($3 <= b[$1] ? $3 : b[$1]) + 1 : $2) + 1; b[$1] = b[$1] <= $3 ? $3 : b[$1]} END {OFS="\t"; print "ID", "count"; for (i in s) {print i, s[i]}}'`

Comment: @pmf: Gotta break out the 3 hand finger calculator for that awk! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MList::Util=uniq -wnE'
    ($id, $beg, $end) = split; 
    next if not $beg or $beg =~ /[^0-9]/ or not $end or $end =~ /[^0-9]/;
    push @{$res{$id}}, $beg..$end; 
    }{ 
    for (keys %res) { @{$res{$_}} = uniq sort { $a <=> $b } @{$res{$_}} };
    say Dumper \%res
' data.txt
```

This command-line program ("one-liner") is a demo, please rewrite in a normal program.

The syntax `}{` marks the start of an `END` block -- once all lines from the file have been processed that code runs.  Can write `END { ... }` instead here.

This generates a list of unique and sorted integers for each ID.  If you specifically need a count, just assign the list to a scalar instead

```
for (keys %res) { $res{$_} = uniq sort { $a <=> $b } @{$res{$_}} };
```

Notes

- Checking of whether the fields are numeric is done here with regex since they're assumed integers.  Otherwise, bettern use `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util)
- In newer Perls dereferencing can be done using [postfix dereference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) syntax

  ```
  push $res{$_}->@*, $beg..$end;
  ```
- Sorting is way easier with [Key::Sort](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) (specially in more complex cases)

  ```
  use Key::Sort qw(usort);  # use "isort" if negative ints are possible

  foreach my $id (sort keys %res) {
      $res{$id}->@* = uniq usort $res{$id}->@*;
  }
  ```

  or, to get counts for each ID instead of numbers

  ```
      $res{$id} = uniq usort $res{$id}->@*;
  ```

  Also note library's `_inplace` methods, which would be nice here if it weren't for `uniq`
- I first `sort` and then `uniq` assuming that `uniq` itself uses sorting internally (since `uniq` "*Preserves the order of unique elements*" this would be faster); but if `uniq` *doesn't* sort then it'd be faster to first filter out dupes and then sort.

Comment: @SWK  Updated a lot since posting.  My intent with this was that you use the "demo" command-line program (to be copy-pasted on the command line, and which should work as it stands) to write a nicer, full program.  If there are questions as you do that let me know

Comment: Can we add command to output the count please? Thanks much!!!

Comment: @SWK  I did -- in the last edit (after I posted a comment).  Go over it again please.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
ID  Start   End
A   1   50
A   2   45
A   25  150
A   50  150
A   155 200
A   205 300
B   5   50
B   61  70
B   81  100
C   1   500
```

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new() }}
    h[$F[0]].merge(($F[1].to_i..$F[2].to_i)) if $.>1
END{
    puts "ID\tCount"
    h.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}\t#{v.length}"}
}
' file
```

Or this awk:

```
awk '
FNR>1{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) ss[$1 "|" i]}
END{
    print "ID", "Count"
    for (e in ss) {
        split(e,idx,"\|")
        cnt[idx[1]]++
    }
    for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]
}
' OFS="\t" file
```

Either prints (but the awk may be unordered...):

```
ID  Count
A   292
B   76
C   500
```

---

From comments, *B 50 5 instead of B 5 50, can we make it work please?*

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new() }}
    v1,v2=[$F[1],$F[2]].map(&:to_i)
    h[$F[0]].merge(v1..v2) if $.>1 && v2>v1
END{
    puts "ID\tCount"
    h.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}\t#{v.length}"}
}
' file
```

This should not be necessary though. The `..` operator creates a range that is added to the set of unique values. The range `50..5` is a null value so nothing would be added.

Here is the test in IRB, the Ruby interactive shell:

```
irb(main):043:0> s=Set.new()
=> #<Set: {}>
irb(main):044:0> s.merge(50..5)
=> #<Set: {}>
irb(main):045:0> s.merge(1..5)
=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>
```

So you can see nothing is added.

Comment: For a or some line/s with reverse order such as B 50 5 instead of B 5 50, can we make it work please? Thanks much!!!

Comment: How should a reverse line like that be interpreted? Are those lines just skipped?

Comment: yes those were skipped. data file can be modified using awk print and I wonder how to do in Ruby. Many thanks!!!

Comment: It *should* be a NoOP since `50..5` is a negative range and therfor an empty list. I will add the code in an edit anyway.